# I can't properly load child posts of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm new to PHP and WordPress.

I'm using [Types](http://wordpress.org/plugins/types/) plugin for creating  my custom types (more info at [here](http://wp-types.com/home/types-manage-post-types-taxonomy-and-custom-fields/)).

**Here is my code:**

```
    <?php
        $args = array('post_type' => 'project-list');
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : 
    ?>
    <span><?php echo $post -> post_title; ?></span>
    <ul class="project-list">
        <?php
            $argsChild = array('orderby' => 'post-order', 'order' => 'ASC');
            $mypostsChild = types_child_posts('project', $argsChild);
            foreach ( $mypostsChild as $postChild ) :
        ?>
        <li>
            <p class="project-cost"><?php echo $postChild -> post_title; ?></p>
            <span class="project-name"><?php echo $postChild -> fields['project-name']; ?></span>
            <hr />
            <p class="project-type"><?php echo $postChild -> fields['project-type']; ?></p>
            <hr />
            <span class="project-location"><?php echo $postChild -> fields['project-location']; ?></span>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

    </ul>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**What I expect:**
I need to load the list of projects by their type. For example I need the final output to look like this.

**Project Group Name-1**

proj-1

proj-2

proj-3

**Project Group Name-2**

proj-1

proj-2

proj-3

---

**I've two problems here:**

1: I don't know where to put the parent post "ID", and this code is now rendering me all the projects from all the project lists. I need to load projects separately for every project list (like above).

Q: How can I do this?

2:  I can't sort the posts by their post-order (which is a custom field type). Thus, I noticed that the following part of the code is not working proper.

```
$argsChild = array('orderby' => 'post-order', 'order' => 'ASC');
```

Q:  How can I sort the child posts based on a custom field type, which is "post-order" in my case?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posts haven't any parent or child. Posts are created under categories. You should create some categories and subcategory under category. i.e.

**CATEGORY :Project Group Name-1**
- SUBCATEGORY: pro 1
- SUBCATEGORY: pro 2

**CAT:Project Group Name-2**
- SUBCATEGORY: pro 1
- SUBCATEGORY: pro 2

Moreover, you have created custom post type. There are many ways to retrieve the terms of custom post types depending your spec. However, try the following code to make some sense:

```
<?php
//list terms in a given taxonomy
$taxonomy = 'project-list';
$tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy);
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
 echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '"     title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' .   $tax_term->name.'</a></li>';
}
?>
</ul>
```

Learn more about [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) , [terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) and [taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies). And read this link, you will get more codes what is related to your need. these will help you.

FYI: page has parent or child page

Comment: you gave me an idea. i am going to do this differently. thanks anyway.